# Setting up kafka topic filter

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I am using this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka) to setup a project. Everything works fine until i add customer container factory on my receiver. Here is my `KafkaReciverConfig`.

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "app.topic");
        props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, TopicPayload> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(TopicPayload.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And here is my `Receiver.liste` method

```
@KafkaListener(id = "app.topic", topics = "${app.topic.topicname}", containerFactory = "filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(@Payload TopicPayload payload) {
    LOGGER.info("-------------------- " + payload);
}
```

If i don't specify `containerFactory` it works fine. but the moment i specify (i plan to add some filteration logic here) I get following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' consumerFactory


Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by the KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration class.

In the KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration class, if there is no bean named "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", register kafkaListenerContainerFactory as bean.

Below is the method code to register the kafkaListenerContainerFactory bean in KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

This method takes a ConsumerFactory`<Object, Object>` as an argument. However, the ConsumerFactory you register with is ConsumerFactory `<String, TopicPayload>` So Spring does not find a bean of type ConsumerFactory`<Object, Object>` and throws an exception

The solution is to not register the ConsumerFactory and consumerConfigs as beans. In this case, the ConsumerFactory will be automatically registered as a bean by KafkaAutoConfiguration.(KafkaAutoConfiguration will automatically register the bean only if there is no bean of type ConsumerFactory.)

```
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "app.topic");
    props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}

public ConsumerFactory<String, TopicPayload> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(TopicPayload.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

The simpler method is to use the name kafkaListenerContainerFactory instead of the name filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory.

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "app.topic");
    props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, TopicPayload> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(TopicPayload.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TopicPayload> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

It's a bit difficult to explain. If you know the AutoConfiguration of Spring boot, it will be easy to understand.

I hope my sample works.

Comment: thanks for the effort. i ended up fixing up this with this annotation `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)`